# PHP Websockets Server missing messages

Tags: php, sockets, websocket

I followed this tutorial here and built an application on top of the websocket code used in this example.

https://www.sanwebe.com/2013/05/chat-using-websocket-php-socket

Everything works fine but the websockets keep dropping messages under load.

For example. I have a user that types a chat message and sends it using the websocket code provided in the tutorial. Also the user is getting messages from the server at like 10 updates a second and user is sending messages back to server at maybe 10 updates a second too.

So if the user types a chat message and sends it. Chat message gets sent and nothing happens. As far as I know javascript gets the chat message, turns it into json and sends it to the server and php websocket server never receives it. This happens randomly and sometimes in a row. It was a lot worse on a VPS. Once I switched to dedicated server it was happening much less.

This doesn't affect only chat messages. It can be any websockets messages sent 
to server. If javascript sends only one message to php websocket server then that message is most likely the one to go missing. So even a ping pong messages can go missing.

This is all happening while server is under load from clients. 
Example
Client:Ping 
Server:Pong
Client:Ping
*Nothing happens*
Client:Ping
Server:Pong
Client:Ping
Server:Pong
Client:Ping
*Nothing happens*
Client:Ping
*Nothing happens*
Client:Ping
*Nothing happens*
Client:Ping 
Server:Pong

Is the code in the php websocket tutorial gone bad? Can it be fixed or do I totally have to redo my code to fit in php Ratchet?

Comment: Line 59 of server.php breaks you out of your while and foreach loops. In short, if there are multiple messages handled at one time, only the first will be processed, based on the tutorial's source code available at https://github.com/sanwebe/Chat-Using-WebSocket-and-PHP-Socket/blob/master/server.php

Comment: That makes complete sense. I'll test it out.

Comment: Removing the break 2; Means the server only receives messages and doesn't send anything out unless it happens to be a response to the client message. Closer to the fix but now nothing is showing up from Server.

Comment: Tested it out, it is stuck looping in the while loop. So it never finishes receiving and responding to messages till it gets the next one...

Comment: Ok more testing...I let it loop three times in while loop for a single client's messages. Have not noticed it eating any messages yet. Given a higher message rate I'm sure it would eat the messages but for now it works ok.